# Instantons and Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, symmetry-breaking, instantons, functional-determinants

I'm following [an introductory lecture on instantons](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0009136) by Hilmar Forkel. In a non-relativistic quantum mechanical setting we have the potential $$ V(x) = \dfrac{\alpha^2 m}{2 x_0^2} (x^2 - x_0^2)^2 \tag{2.42}$$ with the *instanton* solution
$$
x_I (\tau) = - x_0 \tanh \alpha (\tau - \tau_0) \tag{2.51}.
$$
We also have the operator
$$\hat{F}[x_{cl}] := -m^2 \dfrac{d^2}{d \tau^2} + \dfrac{d^2 V(x_{cl})}{d x^2}\tag{2.32}$$ satisfying an eigenvalue problem $$\hat{F}[x_{cl}] \tilde{x}_n = \lambda_n \tilde{x}_n\tag{2.34}$$ for a certain set of orthogonal $\tilde{x}_n$.

Now, it is claimed above eq. (2.60) that

> Since the instanton “spontaneously” breaks the time-translation symmetry of $V$ there must be a zero-mode in the spectrum of $\hat{F}$ (for $T → ∞$).

Can you please explain to me *how* "the instanton spontaneously breaks the time symmetry of $V$"? Is it because there's a particular $\tau_0$ around which "most of the transition is done", so time translation is broken? Or is there anything else?

And, most importantly, how does that entail the existence of a mode with $\lambda_0 = 0$?

Comment: Concerning the last question, an explanation is given in the text: "The physical origin of this zero mode is quite obvious: it corresponds to an infinitesimal shift of the
instanton center τ0, i.e. an infinitesimal time translation of the instanton solution. Since the resulting shifted instanton is degenerate with the original one, such a fluctuation costs no action and (2.35) implies
that the corresponding eigenvalue of ˆF , i.e. λ0, must be zero".  Is there something specific you do not understand about this?

Comment: How does the zero mode correspond to a shift of the instanton centre? And why the shifted instanton is degenerate with the original one?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114723/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For precision's sake let's define the time-translation operator $\hat{T}(\Delta \tau)$ as the operator acting on functions $f$ of $\tau$ as
\begin{equation}
(\hat{T}(\Delta \tau)f)(\tau) = f(\tau + \Delta \tau)\,.
\end{equation}

Clearly we have $(\hat{T}(\Delta\tau)x_I) \neq x_I$ for generic values of $\Delta \tau$ thus the instanton solution break the time-translation symmetry of the system. On the other hand what is called $\tau_0$ you will find when you continue your study on instantons is what is usually called a *modulus* (you will see the term *moduli space* a bunch). You can think of the term modulus as a synonim of parameter most of the time. I will change you notation to make the dependence on the modulus explicit so that
\begin{equation}
x_I(\tau, \tau_0) := x_0 \tanh(\alpha(\tau - \tau_0))\,.
\end{equation}

These are solutions of the classical Euclidean equations of motion for all values of the modulus $\tau_0$. On the other hand $\hat{F}[x_\text{cl}]$ (I use square brackets because this is really an operator-valued *functional* of the classical trajectory $x_\text{cl}(\tau)$) is related to the saddle point expansion around the classical trajectory $x_\text{cl}$:
\begin{equation}
S_E[x_\text{cl} + \delta x] = S_E[x_\text{cl}] + \frac{1}{2}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}d\tau \delta x(\tau)\hat{F}[x_\text{cl}]\delta x(\tau) + O(\delta x^3)
\end{equation}

But then suppose I move in the moduli space (which means I am changing the modulus $\tau_0$), wherever I move I always find solutions to the classical equations of motions which thus extremize $S_E$. Suppose I move of an infinitesimal $\delta \tau_0$, what I get is
\begin{equation}
x_I(\tau, \tau_0 + \delta\tau_0) = x_I(\tau, \tau_0) + \partial_{\tau_0}x_I(\tau, \tau_0) \delta \tau_0 + O(\delta \tau_0^2)\,.
\end{equation}
Since these are all minima of the action we must have $S_E[x_I(\tau, \tau_0 + \delta\tau_0)] = S_E[x_I(\tau, \tau_0)]$, thus
\begin{equation}
\hat{F}[x_I]\partial_{\tau_0}x_I(\tau, \tau_0) = 0
\end{equation}
which is your zero-mode. You will thus sometimes find the description of moduli as flat directions (a continuous line of minima) in some space, in this case its flat directions of the action functional.

By this explanation we also found the actual zero-mode expression as $\partial_{\tau_0}x_I$ which you see in your notes as (2.60), up to normalization of course.

Short version of this is: realize that for all values of $\tau_0$ the instanton is a solution to the classical equations of motion, thus there has to be a continuum of points in trajectory space (the space you integrate over in the path integral) which minimizes the action. Since $\hat{F}$ is basically the Hessian and there is a flat direction it has to have a zero eigenvalue

Comment: Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0):

Solution
$$
x_I (\tau) = - x_0 \tanh \alpha (\tau - \tau_0) .
$$
presents an instanton that at $\tau\rightarrow -\infty$ is in the right well ($x_I\rightarrow 1$), whereas at $\tau\rightarrow +\infty$ is in the left well ($x_I\rightarrow 1$), i.e., it is an instanton moving from right to left. Obviously, for every an instanton moving from right to left, there is another one, moving from left to right:
$$
x_I (\tau) = x_0 \tanh \alpha (\tau - \tau_0) .
$$